# how does the Validation work in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, validation, spring-annotations

i have a field like that:

```
@NotNull(message = "the id must not be null")
@LocationIdValidation
private Integer locationId;
```

@LocationIdValidation is my custom validation annotation, task of this annotation is to check if an id being exist or not in my db ( so the given id must not be null)

when i put locationId is null, it doesnt throw me a message  "the id must not be null" (, but still check the id null or not in @LocationIdValidation, and throw an exception in my log:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!

why does it work??? i think it will throw  a message  "the id must not be null" and stop validating??
tks all!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.